# Regular Expression only match if String ends with target

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will only match to the String if it ends with the target that I am looking for. I need to locate a file with a specific extension, problem is this extension also comes in other files. For example I have two files named

```
B82177_2014-07-08T141507758Z.ccf
```

and

```
B82177_2014-07-08T141507758Z.ccf.done
```

I only want to grab the first of these and my pattern is:

```
.*\.ccf
```

but this grabs both.

Any suggestions appreciated, I am a newbie to regular expressions.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Use an [end anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (`$`):

```
.*\.ccf$
```

This will match any string that ends with `.ccf`, or in multi-line mode, any line that ends with `.ccf`.

Comment: What if there is a query string after the file extension?

Comment: @AbrahamBrookes This question asks specifically about a string that ends with a knwon sequence of characters. If that's not your use case, you'll need to be a lot more specific about what you actually need. Feel free to ask a question (But note that for regex questions, you really should explain what you've tried).

Answer (score 24):

$ is used to match the end of the string.
and can be used like

```
"string"$
```

like

```
xyz$
```

if you want to end with xzy

Answer (score 1):

VanilaJS function base example

```js
function isValidUrl(x){
  let expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
  let regex = new RegExp(expression);
  
  return x.match(regex) ? true : false
  
}

console.log( isValidUrl('www.domain.com') ) // true

console.log( isValidUrl('nothing') ) // false
```