# How to find an element with an id using regex python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to identify an element using an id or name which has dynamic text in the beginning and last part of it constant. How I can find it ?

```
import re
```

I am trying like

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id(r".*username")
elem.send_keys(user)
```

Comment: to clarify, could you give more details on what is 'constant' and what is 'dynamic' text in your application? also I think it might be confusing to use the term `id` here since python objects also have ids.

Comment: You will need to: give more details what is the exact pattern you are parsing, what exactly you tried, and what goes wrong with what you tried. We can't help you much with the information you have provided...

Comment: Please at least provide some example data. Also, be aware that there are various services to help develop regexes: https://regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

You must use `$` in your expression

You can check [Regular Expression only match if String ends with target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24636814/10570576)

It will help you to build your own needed expression