# Regex Get only last 32 random digit and numbers

Tags: c#, regex

Hello I'm having a little problem with getting the last 32 random digits and numbers (ID)

here's the example links

```
 LINK 1:   https://www.testurl/9c47c746-21e6-457a-a557-e5f93bdfff05/056c623a-9327-40d2-8ed7-c349dac76f0d
 LINK 2:   https://www.testurl/a08e9b68-e65b-4beb-b112-fd4360915e82
```

here's the Regex I'm using:
(it's only match the first 32 random digits and numbers which is from LINK 2)

**`(\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12})`**

I also want to get only the "056c623a-9327-40d2-8ed7-c349dac76f0d" from the "LINK 1" after the slash

Comment: Add `$` at the end: `\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}$`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/AhHGDP/1

Comment: Duplicate of [Regular Expression only match if String ends with target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636814/regular-expression-only-match-if-string-ends-with-target)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @41686d6564

answer:

```
\b\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}$
```